# Vim not firing inotify events when writing file

Tags: save, file

Mentioned here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312794/inotify-dont-treat-vim-editting-as-a-modification-event

Really frustrating issue, how can I force vim to write the file?

It seems Vim does something strange when writing a file. It does not seem to invoke any of the  `[Create, Modify, CloseWrite, Move]` inotify events. Only initially. on the first change.

Seems that it "deletes" the file, and hence the inotify watch becomes invalid (hence only works once)... How can I work around this?

Comment: Can you try the utility _entr_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a hint to one solution here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188873/using-inotifywait-along-with-vim

```
:set backupcopy=yes
```

Seems there may be some risk with this approach though.

Comment: You actually need to *disable* backupcopy for that, and the command is `set nobackupcopy` (not `backupcopy=no` or something like that...)

Comment: That gave me an error, maybe cause I'm using neovim?

Comment: actually you're correct, it's a string... But it seems to me you need `backupcopy=no` for the rewrite to happen and trigger inotify.

Comment: One other thing you can do is set an inotify on the *directory* (not file) and look for rename (move_to) actions there, look for the filename that was moved there and see if it matches the one you were looking for. But it would be really hard to do that with `inotifywait`, I think you probably need a C or Python etc. tool that would implement that for you...

Comment: @filbranden `yes` means to copy the file to create a backup and then overwrite the original. So inotify will trigger. `no` means that the original file is renamed to create a backup and a new file with the original name is created.

Comment: @Ralf Hmmm, that's the opposite of what the linked post says: *"Vim can be told to use the overwrite strategy: **turn off** the backupcopy option (:set nobackupcopy). This is risky, as indicated above."* But they also got the "nobackupcopy" part wrong, so I wonder what else in there is incorrect...

Answer (score 6):

Which inotify events are fired depends on how Vim writes the file. This is
controlled by multiple options.

In a typical setup it works like this. Assume Vim wants to write the file `e.txt`

1. Vim moves the file `e.txt` to `e.txt~`
2. Vim creates a new file `e.txt` and writes its content

In this case the event `MOVE_SELF` would be fired. As tools like `inotifywait`
(with `-m` for "monitor") monitor the file by inode, so it would now in fact
monitor the backup file `e.txt~`.

If Vim writes the same file again, the sequence is like this (note: the backup file already exists):

1. Vim deletes the backup file `e.txt~`
2. Vim moves the file `e.txt` to `e.txt~`
3. Vim creates a new file `e.txt` and writes its content

So a monitoring `inotifywait` will receive a `DELETE_SELF` because the backup
file is deleted. Now it listens to changes to an unused inode and will not
print anything anymore.

If the file `e.txt` is in fact a symbolic link to the file `tgt.txt`, Vim acts different:

1. Vim copies the content of `tgt.txt` (the symlinked file) to the backup file `e.txt~`
2. Vim writes the content to `tgt.txt`.

In this case a monitoring `inotifywait` will see the `CLOSE_WRITE` (and other) events.

The behavior how Vim saves the file is controlled by the option `backupcopy`.
In `nocompatible` mode it is set to `auto`. This means that Vim decides which
is the best way to save a file. Hence the two different behaviors described above.

If `backupcopy` is set to `yes`, Vim will always create the backup file by copying the original file. In this case `inotifywait` is able to monitor the file.

If `backupcopy` is set to `no`, Vim will always create the backup file by
moving the original file. In this case `inotifywait` is *not* able to monitor
the file. This also has the disadvantage that it will break symbolic links.

See `:help 'backupcopy'`. This describes the pros and cons of the different values.

---

So back to `inotify`: How to monitor a file saved by Vim?

Assuming you want to monitor the file `/home/joedoe/e.txt` for `CLOSE_WRITE`
events in a shell script:

```
file=/home/joedoe/e.txt
file_dir="$(dirname "$file")"
inotifywait -mqe close_write --format "%w%f" "$file_dir" |
    while read -r filename; do
        if [ "$filename" = "$file" ]; then
            # do what needs to be done
            ....
        fi
    done
```

This way you are independent from the strategy Vim uses for saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens with Vim it's likely due to the way it 'saves' a file (it does this to avoid data loss). As a workaround, we can instead use `inotify` to watch the parent directory instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

watchThisFile="z.sh"

inotifywait -r -m . | 
   while read -r file_path file_event file_name; do
       if echo "$file_name" | grep -q "$watchThisFile"; then               
         echo "$watchThisFile was modified"
       else
         echo "Skipping:"
         echo "$file_path $file_event $file_name"
       fi
   done
```

Comment: Using a filename as the pattern for `grep` is probably not correct; in particular, `grep z.sh` will match `zash`, `z0sh`, etc. Better might be [this if your Grep supports `-z`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47541882/4400820), but `-F` is POSIX and would fix this specific case.